# Windows Server 2008 With VPN Client Always On

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

I have a Windows Server 2008 Ent VPS that I have setup to connect to my hone VPN server. I'm able to get connected to the VPN but it disconnects me when I logout.

Is there a way I can setup the server to keep the VPN Connection alive even when I log out from RDC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [persistent demand-dial connections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771337(WS.10).aspx) in Routing and Remote Access Service. That'll do what you want to do re: an always-on VPN connection.

Answer (score -1):

I done this in way:
- create vpn connection, save password allow all users to use this connection
- download autoconnect application (http://www.instalki.pl/programy/download/Windows/sieciowe/AutoConnect.html) - Polish version and configure autoconnection of my vpn created above
- create scheduled task that this app above will start after system boot
- run this task

it works 2 days now and it is ok.